# How do I calculate the cartesian coordinates of stars

Tags: trigonometry

Given the Right ascension in h m s, Declination in deg ' " and the Trigonometric parallax How can I get the cartesian (x,y,z) coordinates of a star? I'm guessing I need 3 separate formulas to get each x, y and z values.

Comment: Why do you need Cartesian coordinates? [In any event...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celestial_coordinate_system)

Comment: Then your declination corresponds to $\theta$, right ascension to $\phi$ and parallax to $r$ for a properly referenced spherical coordinate system. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system

Comment: @J.M.  to plot thing in openGL you need Cartesian coordinates.  @Ross - Thanks I'll look into it.

Comment: Another use is for those running Sci-Fi games (wargames or rpgs); it's much easier to find the distance from system A to B if the reference points are cartesian instead of RA/dec/Dist from Earth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this is old, but here is the answer:

http://fmwriters.com/Visionback/Issue14/wbputtingstars.htm

A = (RA_hours * 15) + (RA_minutes * 0.25) + (RA_seconds * 0.004166)

B = ( ABS(Dec_degrees) + (Dec_minutes / 60) + (Dec_seconds / 3600)) * SIGN(Dec_Degrees)

C = distance in light years or parsecs

**Cartesian:**

X = (C * cos(B)) * cos(A)

Y = (C * cos(B)) * sin(A)

Z = C * sin(B)